# How to setup Jenkins to build an maven project from other maven projects with dependencies within the application

Tags: java, maven, github, jenkins, build

We have 4 `projects`.

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

`A`, `B`, `C` do not have local dependencies on other projects within our application.

Project `D` requires the dependency on `A`, `B`, `C`.

I am curious how to setup Jenkins to be able to build project `D`.  Do I need to update the maven pom file to build from our jenkins server as the repository dependency or is this possible to setup via jenkins directly to be able to use the targets from `A`, `B`, `C` when building `D`.

All of the repositories are stored in `Github`.

**UPDATE**

Do I want to be setting these projects up as a "Maven Project", "Pipeline" or "Freestyle Project"?

I can see that you can set post action to "Deploy artifacts to Maven Repository", would I then also set it up to "Build other projects" so when A/B/C are built they all setup to have "Build Other Projects" of D?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parameterized-trigger` with `"Block until the triggered projects finish their builds"` option to tell jenkins to:

- Trigger build on A, B and C when D is built
- Block D build execution until A, B and C are successfully built.

Suppose 4 projects are built on one jenkins node, then A, B and C artifacts will be install on the node's local repo `.m2` when their maven builds succeed, and D can find them directly. You don't have to change your pom.

Comment: @Rocheriee     I am building A B C now and when I go to build D it does not detect the other project's jar files.  I also dont see "parameterized-trigger" in the setup of a freestyle project do I have to set this up as a maven project instead?

Comment: Make sure maven goal is `clean install` for A, B and C build. Checking console output to see whether their artifacts are installed to `/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/` dir. `parameterized-trigger` is an external plugin you need to install.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how often you want build for  D.

Option 1 : Project D depends on snapshot builds of A,B,C and will be triggered  after any of the upstream builds (A,B,C) successfully builds. This option is good when D is just an aggregator for A,B,C

Option 2 : Configure pom of project D when ever stable build of A,B,C to be consumed.

In both the options D can build independently when there are changes only in project D.